# Need help installing BlueGriffon

Tags: installation

I'm having trouble figuring out how to install [BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/). All the other programs I've installed have been easily found in the Software Center or were a .deb that opened into the Software Center, but BlueGriffon's download is a **.tar.bz2** and I tried to look for information on how to use that but it was all outdated and didn't help.

So if possible could anyone please just give me a walk-through on how to install this and get it running? Thank you for your time.

/edit: ran `ls ~/Downloads/bluegriffon` and this resulted:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

*(Notice that I have assumed you saved your `bluegriffon` in your Downloads folder, so you should make the necessary changes otherwise. I also assumed you are using Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit)*

Open a terminal and

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xjf bluegriffon-1.7.Ubuntu13.04-i686.tar.bz2
```

after that you can run BlueGriffon by typing (in a terminal):

```
~/Downloads/bluegriffon/bluegriffon
```

If you want to be able to see BlueGriffon in the Unity Dash (or GNOME Activies, etc) you should create a `.desktop` file, for example, using GEdit (Text Editor) type:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Blue Griffon
Comment=Web editor
TryExec=/home/your-username/Downloads/bluegriffon/bluegriffon
Exec=/home/your-username/Downloads/bluegriffon/bluegriffon %u
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/home/your-username/Downloads/bluegriffon/chrome/icons/default/default48.png
```

(Change `your-username` with your actual user name!) Save this file with the name `BlueGriffon.desktop` to the folder `~/.local/share/applications` and that's it.

Comment: Do I just paste in that first part right into the terminal or do I need to manually type it in? When I just pasted it in I got this 
'tar (child): bluegriffon-1.7.Ubuntu13.04-i686.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory'
Sorry I'm not getting it quite right when you took all the time to type this up for me ^^;; do you know what I am doing wrong here? (accidentally hit enter too soon so I had to edit..)

Comment: It won't work unless you have saved the file in your Downloads folder. Try moving `bluegriffon-1.7.Ubuntu13.04-i686.tar.bz2` to the Downloads folder and then you can just copy paste the code into a terminal.

Comment: ah, okay, apparently I had downloaded the 64bit file instead of the 32bit file so the name was different and thus the code did not work correctly, I did it again and it seemed to work (didn't give me any error), but then when I did the second part to run it I'm gettting this _~/Downloads/bluegriffon/bluegriffon
/home/danica/Downloads/bluegriffon/bluegriffon-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory_ Sorry for being so hard to help, thank you for your patience.

Comment: Are you using Ubutun 13.04?? Or is it version 12.04?

Comment: oh my, sorry I'd completely forgotten I should have included that. I'm using version 13.04.

Comment: That's weird, I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and it works just fine. Run `ls ~/Downloads/bluegriffon` and edit your quetion to include its result.

Comment: Open a terminal and `cd Downloads/bluegriffon` then run `./bluegriffon`. If it doesn't work try `sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-2`, and try `./bluegriffon` again...

Comment: No problem here, Ubuntu 16.04 g4 bits.  UPVOTED :)